# jquery autocomplete remove focus after suggest

Tags: jquery, focus, jquery-autocomplete

After selecting an item in the autocomplete list, my script validates the selection but does not release the focus. Ive even tried to place focus on another element to my dissapointment.

This is my code:

```
var usernames = [<? print_r($jquery_usernames); ?>];
            $("#suggest1").autocomplete(usernames); 
            $("#suggest1").result(function() {
                    $(this).submit();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                      $('#focusdiv').focus();
                    }, 1);                  
                });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest that you post the rendered (as it appears in the browser, under 'view source') jQuery; since JavaScript, and therefore jQuery, work in the client, not the server.

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting and works (the focus is removed from the suggest1 input):

```
$("#suggest1").autocomplete(usernames); 
        $("#suggest1").result(function() {
                $(this).submit();                   
                setTimeout(function() {
                  $('.next-step').focus();
                }, 1);                  
            });
```

Note: It doesnt work without the setTimeout function.
'.next-step' is a clickable href (tabbed form)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the blur event? I.E. `$('#suggest1').blur();`

Comment: blur doesnt work either - I think the issue has something to do with the validation which keeps the focus on #suggest1 after the autocomplete.